# UI testing tools for Win32 app written in C?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, windows, desktop-application, c

I have a game written in C, and I would like to write UI tests for it. Are there any suitable frameworks for testing UI's written in C? Both the game logic and the UI are written in C.

Comment: What is written on C? Game logic or UI?

Comment: Game logic and UI :/

Answer (score 2):

For Windows UI automation testing, you can use pywinauto: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto

It has a strong community, and it's developer [Vasily Ryabov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3648361/vasily-ryabov) is active on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pywinauto)

Comment: Great find! Using a highly productive (for a programmer) language like Python to write parts of the app which are not performance-critical (like UI tests)  is great design decision, and good news that devs are working on a version automating Linux desktop. I do not need it currently, but will remember it in case I might need it in the future.